# How do you properly rig a model or limit a bones "effect radius"

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, bones

***What I am trying to do:***

I am trying to simply have the arm of my model spin without affecting any parts of my model except the arm itself when the upper arm spins. Like the image below, that is exactly how I want my model to behave when I rotate the upper arm after rigging my model.

[image]

***What the issue is:***

When I give my model weights and rig it to its skeleton, it seems to drag the pauldrons, cloak of my model, and everything else around it in a circle with the arm when I attempt to rotate the arm in a circle, unlike the image above. The "effect radius of the bone" seems to be the cause of this. Is there any way to limit this specifically so I can limit it to the size of the upper arm.

[image]
[image]

Comment: did u try set parent to bone?

Comment: Is your whole character joined together or are they still separate objects? If they are still separate objects there is a solution to your problem if what you are trying to do is make specific singular bones affect specific singular parts of your mesh.

Comment: it can be either, I can start from scratch have time stamped blender saves of the model so I can revert

Comment: anyways I thought the point of the skeleton was to target specific parts of the mesh